# if/else do nothing for class inside td

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying the make the `else` do nothing. I would like to know if there's something wrong with this code? Any help?

```
if ($("div.pl_media_folder:first")){
    $('#pl_medias tr').attr('id', 'table-row-id');
    $('#pl_medias tr').attr('class', 'table-row-class');
} else {
    // Do nothing..
}
```

It's adding the id and the class attribute for all the tr, I want to add them just for the ones that contain the class pl_media_folder inside the TD

Comment: Can you specify your goal? I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if you don't want the `else` statement to do anything you can simply remove it. Secondly, your logic isn't quite right as the `if` condition will always be true (due to objects coercing to `true`) and you don't need the `if` statement anyway.

To add the id and class to `tr` elements which contain a `div.pl_media_folder` then you can use `has()` like this:

```
$('#pl_medias tr').has('div.pl_media_folder').prop({
  'id': 'table-row-id',
  'class': 'table-row-class'
});
```

Note that you will need to be careful with this logic as if there are multiple `tr` found you will be duplicating the same `id`, which is invalid.